# Solution of equation with power series (perturbation)

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion

So I need to use *Mathematica* to find the solution of $y=x- \epsilon \sin(2y)$ as a power series in terms of $\epsilon$. I'd assume I'd need to create an equation $f=x-y- \epsilon \sin(2y)$, then express $y(\epsilon)=\sum_n a_n  \epsilon^n$, then input into series, but I can't seem to get it to work.
Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello Lenny! Welcome to the *Mathematica* StackExchange community. Have you tried to do anything by yourself? I mean, is there any piece of code which you've tried to use?

Comment: I have. What I have tried so far:
eq[eps_,y_]:=x-eps Sin[2y];
y[eps_]:=Sum[Subscript[a,n] eps^n,{n,0,20}];
Series[eq[eps,y[eps]],{eps,0,2}];

Comment: Is `eps` any *Mathematica* function? Or is it just an argument of a function?

Comment: eps is just epsilon

Comment: Hi @Lenny, I edited you post for more readability, please do click the **edited** link above my avatar to see how I did it. Also please refer to the [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: About your question, I think you might be interested in the [Kepler's Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_equation), which is of the very similar form, and has been studied deeply.

Comment: I have already looked but that does not really help me

Comment: Hint: let $x=3\eta/2-\xi, y=\eta/2$, then your equation will reduce to Kepler's Equation.

Comment: I would like to know a systematic way to solve this question. for example, if the equation was $$y=2x-\epsilon Cos[2y]$$

Comment: I don't see any difference. You can still use linear transformation to reduce to Kepler Eq.

Comment: I don't want to reduce it into Kepler though....

Comment: It's just I think this type of equations are not as innocent as they look like, so instead of trying it with trivial methods, adopting some sophisticated results might be more meaningful. Anyway, you can try [this method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25398/17).

Answer (score 6):

Let define the equation to solve $f=x-y\epsilon\sin(2 x)\equiv 0$ and series expansion of $y$ in powers of $\varepsilon$.

```
f = x - y - \[Epsilon] Sin[2 y];
ord = 3;
y = x + Sum[a[n] \[Epsilon]^n, {n, ord}] + O[\[Epsilon]]^(ord + 1);
```

Then expand the equation and solve for any value of $\varepsilon$ parameter

```
eqs = Normal[Series[f, {\[Epsilon], 0, ord}]];
SolveAlways[eqs == 0, \[Epsilon]]
(* => {{a[3] -> 2 (a[1] - a[1]^3 + a[1] Cos[4 x]), a[2] -> -2 a[1] Cos[2 x], Sin[2 x] -> -a[1]}} *)
```

If we are interested in the expansion coefficients $a_n$ in terms of $x$ then following code will refine the solution

```
sol = First@Solve[Equal@@@First@SolveAlways[eqs == 0, \[Epsilon]], a/@Range[ord]]
(* => {a[1] -> -Sin[2 x], a[2] -> 2 Cos[2 x] Sin[2 x],  a[3] -> 2 Sin[2 x] (-1 - Cos[4 x] + Sin[2 x]^2)} *)
```

One should also do check

```
f/.sol//Simplify
(* => O[\[Epsilon]]^4 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

The new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) can be used to find the perturbation expansions:

```
AsymptoticSolve[y == x - ϵ Sin[2 y], {y, x}, {ϵ, 0, 4}]
```

> {{y -> x - ϵ Sin[2 x] + 2 ϵ^2 Cos[2 x] Sin[2 x] - 
>       2 ϵ^3 (2 Cos[2 x]^2 Sin[2 x] - Sin[2 x]^3) + 
>       8/3 ϵ^4 (3 Cos[2 x]^3 Sin[2 x] - 5 Cos[2 x] Sin[2 x]^3)}}

in agreement with mmal's answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, one can express $\varepsilon$ as a function of $y$:

```
Clear[eps]
eps[y_] = ε /. Solve[x == y - ε Sin[2 y], ε][[1]]
```

$$-(x-y) \csc (2 y).$$

Then, expand into series around $y=x$, since it is a solution for $\varepsilon=0$. Applying `InverseSeries` after that gives:

```
res = InverseSeries[Series[eps[y], {y, x, 3}]] /. y -> ε // FullSimplify
```

$$x+\varepsilon  \sin (2 x)+\varepsilon ^2 \sin (4 x)+\varepsilon ^3 \sin (2 x) (3 \cos (4 x)+1)+O\left(\varepsilon ^4\right).$$

Check:

```
Series[y - ε Sin[2 y] /. y -> res, {ε, 0, 3}] // FullSimplify
```

$$x+O\left(\varepsilon ^4\right).$$