# How do I find a series solution for $e^{-\frac{1}{2}f'(x)} \mathrm{cosh}( f(x) ) = ax + b$?

Tags: series-expansion

I am trying to approximate a function $f(x)$ satisfying a relation between $f(x)$ and its first derivative. How do I find a series solution for $$e^{-\frac{1}{2}f'(x)} \mathrm{cosh}( f(x) ) = ax + e^{-\frac{1}{2}f'(0)}$$ about $x=0$? Thus far I've looked at the numerical solution.

```
s = NDSolve[ { -0.5*y'[x] + Log[Cosh[y[x]]] == 
    1 + Log[ 0.1*y[x] + Exp[-1 - 0.25 ]] , y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 4} ]
Plot[Evaluate[ y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All ]
```

And if this were a linear ODE I could use `Series[DifferentialRoot[ ] ]`.

Comment: Could you please post the Mathematica code for your equations so we don't have to retype them?

Comment: I'm entirely new to Mathematica. I looked up how to define differential operators and nobody seems to agree. So I'm looking for best practice.

Comment: So I recommend searching this site for `DSolve[]` before asking

Comment: Related: [25363](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25363), [26938](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26938)

Comment: (1) Always helpful to write the input as explicit Mathematica (InputForm) code. Something like `Exp[-1/2*D[f[x],x]]*...`. (2) Possibly what you want is to subtract rhs from lhs, take `ser = Series[..., {x,0,4}]` for example, and then `SolveAlways[ser,x]`. (I'd test it but you didn't include that input...)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Series Expansion**

Answering the question we show how to construct the series expansion of `f[x]` about `x=0`.

From the basic equation we find

```
f'[x]==2(Log[a x + b]-Log[Cosh[f[x]]])
```

the derivative of `f[x]` in terms of the function `f[x]` itself and some other terms.

Hence in the Taylor expansion of the function

```
f[x] = f[0] + x f'[0] + x^2/2! f''[0] + x^3/3! f'''[x] + ...
```

we can replace `f'[x]` by

```
g[x_] = 2 (Log[a x + b] - Log[Cosh[f[x]]]);
```

`f''[x]` is then replaced by `g'[x]` which in turn is expressed by `f[x]` via

```
g'[x]

(* Out[62]= a/(b + a x) - Tanh[f[x]] Derivative[1][f][x] *)
```

where `f'[x]` on the right hand side must be replaced by `g[x]` and so on.

This means that all coefficients of the Tayor expansion are expressed in terms of `f[0]`, `a`, and `b`.

In order to formalize this procedure in Mathematica we define recursively the auxiliary functions

```
g[k_, x_] := D[g[k - 1, x], x] /. f'[x] -> g[x]
g[1, x_] = g[x];
```

The first few functions are

```
Table[g[k, x], {k, 1, 3}] // Column
```

$\begin{array}{l}
 \{\text{Log}[b+a x]-\text{Log}[\text{Cosh}[f[x]]]\} \\
 \left\{\frac{a}{b+a x}-(\text{Log}[b+a x]-\text{Log}[\text{Cosh}[f[x]]]) \text{Tanh}[f[x]]\right\} \\
 \left\{-\frac{a^2}{(b+a x)^2}-(\text{Log}[b+a x]-\text{Log}[\text{Cosh}[f[x]]])^2 \text{Sech}[f[x]]^2-\text{Tanh}[f[x]] \left(\frac{a}{b+a x}-(\text{Log}[b+a x]-\text{Log}[\text{Cosh}[f[x]]]) \text{Tanh}[f[x]]\right)\right\} \\
\end{array}$

Hence the requested series expansion to order n is given by

```
fs[x_, n_] := f[0] + Sum[x^k/k! (g[k, x] /. x -> 0), {k, 1, n}]
```

Example `n=3`

```
fs[x, 3]
```

$\text{f0}+x (\text{Log}[b]-\text{Log}[\text{Cosh}[\text{f0}]])+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \left(\frac{a}{b}-(\text{Log}[b]-\text{Log}[\text{Cosh}[\text{f0}]]) \text{Tanh}[\text{f0}]\right)+\frac{1}{6} x^3 \left(-\frac{a^2}{b^2}-(\text{Log}[b]-\text{Log}[\text{Cosh}[\text{f0}]])^2 \text{Sech}[\text{f0}]^2-\text{Tanh}[\text{f0}] \left(\frac{a}{b}-(\text{Log}[b]-\text{Log}[\text{Cosh}[\text{f0}]]) \text{Tanh}[\text{f0}]\right)\right)$

**Numerical calculation of f(x) via an ODE**

This was my original text, which, however, is not an answer to the problem.

Solving for f' you can write your equation as an ODE

```
eq = f'[x]/2 == Log[a x + b] - Log[Cosh[f[x]]];
```

Then solve it numerically after having defined the values of the parameters a and b.

For example

```
a = 1; b = 1;
ff[x_] = f[x] /. 
  NDSolve[f'[x]/2 == Log[a x + b] - Log[Cosh[f[x]]] && f[0] == 1, f[x], {x, -2, 10}][[1]]
```

Plot the function

```
Plot[ff[x], {x, -2, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]
(* 141107_NDSolve.jpg *)
```

[image]

You can play with the values of the parameters and the initial condition to adapt the problem to the situation you want.

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Another way to accomplish the effect of `g`: `dfrule = f'[x] -> 2 (Log[a x + b] - Log[Cosh[f[x]]]); NestList[D[First[#], x] -> (D[Last[#], x] /. dfrule) &, dfrule, 3] /. x -> 0`, where `3` may be replaced by any `k`.

Comment: You've not only answered my question but got me up to speed with the software. Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks to the (unknown) upvoters.

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled across this question just now, but it seems to me that there's a much easier way to do this problem via user-defined `SeriesData` objects.  If we want to define 
$$
f(x) = c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + \dots
$$
it's not too hard to do this in Mathematica:

```
n = 4;  
f[x_] = SeriesData[x, 0, Array[c, n, 0], 0, n, 1]

(* c[0] + c[1] x + c[2] x^2 + c[3] x^3 + O[x]^4 *)
```

Once we've done this, it's pretty easy to get a set of rules relating the $c_i$ coefficients and $a$:

```
SolveAlways[Exp[-f'[x]/2] Cosh[f[x]] == a x + Exp[-f'[0]/2], x];     
FullSimplify[%, Assumptions -> Element[c[_], Reals]]

(* {{a -> E^(-(c[1]/2)) (-c[2] + c[1] Sinh[c[0]]),
     c[3] -> 1/3 (c[1]^2 + c[2]^2 - 2 (-1 + c[1]) c[2] Sinh[c[0]]), 
     Cosh[c[0]] -> 1}} *)
```

Disentangling the above equations, this implies that $c_0 = 0$, $c_2 = -a e^{c_1/2}$, and $c_3 = \frac{1}{3} (c_1^2 + a^2 e^{c_1})$.  The coefficient $c_1$ is freely specifiable.  Note that we must have $c_0 = 0$:  when we plug $x = 0$ into the original equation, we get $\cosh(f(0)) = 1$, or $f(0) = 0$.

If you want to get a direct solution for the $c_i$ coefficients, that's possible too;  it just takes a little more work:

```
Thread[CoefficientList[Normal[Exp[-f'[x]/2] Cosh[f[x]] - (a x + Exp[-f'[0]/2])], x] == 0];
Solve[%, Drop[Array[c, n, 0], {2}]]

(* {{c[0] -> 0, c[2] -> -a E^(c[1]/2), c[3] -> 1/3 (a^2 E^c[1] + c[1]^2)}} *)
```

The `Drop` is necessary so Mathematica doesn't try to solve for the free coefficient $c_1$.  (There's probably a nicer way to do that.)  This method has the advantage that it keeps working even at higher values of $n$;  my first method conks out around $n = 9$ (complaining about the relations being "essentially non-algebraic"), but the second method spits out an answer in about a second.

Answer (score 4):

Using new function `AsymptoticDSolveValue` form Mathematica `11.3`:

```
sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{-y'[x]/2 + Log[Cosh[y[x]]] == 
1 + Log[y[x]/10 + Exp[-(5/4)]], y[0] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 6}]

(* x/2 - 1/20 E^(5/4) x^2 + 
1/240 (20 + E^(5/2)) x^3 + ((-800 E^(5/4) - 
17 E^(15/4)) x^4)/48000 + ((70000 + 10400 E^(5/2) + 
159 E^5) x^5)/4800000 + ((-570000 E^(5/4) - 35900 E^(15/4) - 
487 E^(25/4)) x^6)/144000000*)
```

Comparison with numeric solution:

```
numeric = NDSolve[{-0.5*y'[x] + Log[Cosh[y[x]]] == 
1 + Log[0.1*y[x] + Exp[-1 - 0.25]], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}]

Plot[{sol, Evaluate[y[x] /. numeric]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
PlotLegends -> {"Series", "Numeric"}]
```

[image]