# DSolve gives wrong solution

Tags: differential-equations

```
eq = x^2 f''[x] + x f'[x] - 4 f[x] == 0;
bc = f[∞] == 0; (* boundary condition *)

sol = DSolve[ {eq, bc}, f[x], x]

(* {{f[x] -> 0}} *)
```

The correct solution is `f[x]=c/x^2`. Why does DSolve give a wrong answer?

Comment: Where is the actual equation? I see no ODE here.

Comment: I have an image there. The equation is  x^2 f '' (x) + x f'(x) - 4 f(x) = 0 with boundary condition f(Infinity)=0. DSolve gives f(x)=0 but the correct solution is f(x) = c / x^2

Comment: Clearly, the answer is correct, trivially so.

Comment: f(x)=0 is a solution of the ODE but f(x)=c/x^2 is the general solution. DSolve missed the general solution. Why?

Answer (score 8):

The boundary condition `f[Infinity]==0`is the problem:

You might solve your problem using the general solution

```
sol = DSolve[{x^2 f''[x] + x f'[x] - 4 f[x] == 0}, f, x][[1]]
TrigToExp[ f[x] /. sol]
(* C[1]/(2 x^2) + 1/2 x^2 C[1] - (I C[2])/(2 x^2) + 1/2 I x^2 C[2] *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively to gwr's extension, one could examine the general solution from Ulrich Neumann symbolically:

```
sf = C[1]/(2 x^2) + 1/2 x^2 C[1] - (I C[2])/(2 x^2) + 1/2 I x^2 C[2]
Limit[sf, x->Infinity]
```

> (C[1] + I C[2]) Infinity

We need this expression to equal 0, so set `C[2]->I C[1]`:

```
sf /. C[2] -> I C[1]
```

> C[1]/x^2

To get to the heart of why this happens, I imagine it's because `DSolve` evaluates `Infinity` preemptively. Even after taking the limiting case specifically and seeing the term containing `Infinity`, a bit of a logical leap is required to say that the only way this will work is if `(C[1] + I C[2])` is 0. Even after that leap that term is `Indefinite`, not 0 exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Building upon Ulrich Neumann's answer you may approach the solution by including the boundary condition for arbitrarily large x:

```
eq = x^2 f''[x] + x f'[x] - 4 f[x] == 0;

sol = DSolve[ {eq, f[1.*^60] == 0}, f[x], x] // RightComposition[
    First,
    TrigToExp, 
    FullSimplify,
    N
]
```

> $\text{f}[x] \rightarrow 0. +\frac{1. \text{C[1]}}{x^2}$

Comment: +1 for introducing me to `RightComposition`!

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke You are welcome - I must admit that I tend to use it excessively -- feeling vindicated, though, by looking at more structured code ... ;-)

Comment: Through my previous exposition to functional programming with Haskell i was already a fan of point free style and liked to use `Composition` a lot, it's good to know there are more options that feel more natural in some situations!

Comment: How is `RightComposition` here better than `sol=... // First // TrigToExp // FullSimplify // N`?

Comment: @Ruslan Essentially, there is no difference but the block-writing with `,` makes for better readability and `Composition[ g, h ]` can be immediately treated as a function while `... // g // h` can not.

Answer (score 3):

Further to the other answers:  Mathematica can find the general solution so long as you ask it to solve for the boundary condition $f(a) = 0$ at a finite (but arbitrary) $a$, and only then take the limit $a \to \infty$:

```
sol = DSolve[{x^2 f''[x] + x f'[x] - 4 f[x] == 0, f[a] == 0}, f[x], x][[1]]
Limit[f[x] /. sol, a -> \[Infinity]]

(* {f[x] -> C[1] Cosh[2 Log[x]] - C[1] Coth[2 Log[a]] Sinh[2 Log[x]]} *) 
(* C[1]/x^2 *)
```

See also my answer to [DSolve not satisfying initial conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138853/dsolve-not-satisfying-initial-conditions/138858#138858), which dealt with a similar  problem of `DSolve` missing certain solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Carrying the above solutions further:

```
eq = x^2 f''[x] + x f'[x] - 4 f[x] == 0;

DSolve[eq, f[x], x] // Flatten
(* {f[x] -> C[1]*Cosh[2*Log[x]] + I*C[2]*Sinh[2*Log[x]]} *)

f[x_] = f[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2/I}
(* c1*Cosh[2*Log[x]] + c2*Sinh[2*Log[x]] *)

f[x] // TrigToExp // Collect[#, x^_] &
(* x^2*(c1/2 + c2/2) + (c1/2 - c2/2)/x^2 *)

f[x_] = % /. {c1/2 + c2/2 -> c1, c1/2 - c2/2 -> c2}
(* c1*x^2 + c2/x^2 *)
```

Applying the bc, for `f` to be `0` at `x == infinity`, `c1` must be `0`.