# Finding power series solution for differential equation in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion

I know this topic has been covered before, but I've tried all the solutions I can find from other users' questions and none of them have worked.

I need to find a power series solution to the following nonlinear differential 
equation:

```
y''=x+y^2
```

with initial conditions

```
y(0)=0, y'(0)=0
```

up to the x^4 term. Does anyone have a quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange.  In order to learn how to use this site 
[take the tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). When copying equations from a notebook to your question one should format using inline code  by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  It is recommended that you browse [the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: One of the reasons to do this is to help the users who attempt to answer your question so they can directly copy your equations into a notebook. Otherwise typographical errors can easily occur.

Comment: `seriesDSolve[y''[x] == (x + y[x]^2), y, {x, 0, 13}, {y[0] -> 0, y'[0] -> 0}]` from [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96696/4999) to [(25363)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25363) solves your problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Mathematica should really have Series option to solving ODE's. This option has been there in Maple for ever. I do not understand why Mathematica does not support such a basic option to solving ODE's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not get an x^4 term.

```
findSeriesSolution[y_,x_,nTerms_]:=Module[
{roots,pt=0,ode,s0,s1,ic,eq,sol},ic={y[0]->0,y'[0]->0};
  ode=y''[x]- (x+y[x]^2);
  s0=Series[ode,{x,pt,nTerms}];
  s0=s0/.ic;
  roots=Solve@LogicalExpand[s0==0];
  s1=Series[y[x],{x,pt,nTerms+2}];
  sol=Normal[s1]/.ic/.roots[[1]]
]
```

And now

```
sol = findSeriesSolution[y,x,10]
(*  x^3/6 + x^8/2016 *)
```

Compare

```
Plot[sol,{x,0,1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
solm=NDSolve[{y''[x]-(x+y[x]^2)==0,y[0]==0,y'[0]==0},y,{x,0,1}];
Plot[Evaluate[y[x]/.solm],{x,0,1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Analytical solution is  (thanks to Maple 2017.3)

$$
-\ln  \left( {\frac {1}{{{\rm Ai}\left(-x\right)}{{\rm Bi}^{(1)}\left(
-x\right)}-{{\rm Ai}^{(1)}\left(-x\right)}{{\rm Bi}\left(-x\right)}}
 \left( {\frac { \left( {\it \_C2}\,\sqrt {3}\pi+{3}^{2/3}\Gamma
 \left( 2/3 \right)  \right) {{\rm Ai}\left(-x\right)}}{\pi}}-{\it 
\_C2}\,{{\rm Bi}\left(-x\right)} \right) } \right) -2\,i\pi\,{\it \_Z2
}
$$

Screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica can't at this time solve this analytically. May be in future versions.

```
DSolve[{y''[x] - ( x + y[x]^2) == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]