# Recurrence relation of coeeficients of power series solution to DE

Tags: series-expansion, recursion

Say I have a DE

$$
-\phi  \left(\phi  \left(\left(6975 \phi ^2-3704 \phi +160\right) \omega '(\phi )+\phi 
   \left(\left(6975 \phi ^2-4688 \phi +266\right) \omega ''(\phi )+\phi  \left(2
   \left(675 \phi ^2-518 \phi +32\right) \omega ^{(3)}(\phi )-\phi  \omega ^{(4)}(\phi
   )\right)\right)\right)\right) = 0
$$

and I want a recurrence relation for coefficients of a power series solution, such that the constant term $\omega(0)=1$, how can I do that?

I will change symbols to $t$ and $f$ because they will look nicer here

```
t[f_] := x D[f,x]
R[x_] := -9 x^3 + 5 x^2 - 4 x
L[f_,x_] := R[x] Nest[t,f,4] + R[x]^2 Nest[t,f,3] + f
diffEqn = Expand[L[h[x],x]]
```

Comment: Can you at least rewrite your ODE in *Mathematica*'s format?

Comment: @J.M.isinlimbo i have edited the post

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59961)? The only change needed in your case would be to use `SeriesCoefficient[]` instead of `Series[]`, so that you (hopefully) get a `DifferenceRoot[]` object.

Comment: @J.M.isinlimbo it doesn't give me a recurrence relation. If I only have one initial condition `f[0]==1`, it would say "not a well-formed linear differential equation with initial conditions."