# Successive solutions using previously found

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion, asymptotics

is there a way to use previous calculated values  of solve?

solving equations based on asymptotic expansion

$x^2+x-\varepsilon=0$

$x=x_0+\varepsilon x_1 + \varepsilon^2 x_2 + \varepsilon^3 x_3$

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Collect[Expand[(x0 + e x1 + e^2 x2 + e^3 x3)^2 + (x0 + e x1 + e^2 x2 +
  e^3 x3) - e], e]
```

for some reason output isn't grouped in ascending/descending powers of `e`

`x0 + x0^2 + e (-1 + x1 + 2 x0 x1) + e^2 (x1^2 + x2 + 2 x0 x2) + 2 e^5 x2 x3 + e^6 x3^2 + e^3 (2 x1 x2 + x3 + 2 x0 x3) + e^4 (x2^2 + 2 x1 x3)`

but anyways, copying one by one

```
Solve[x0 + x0^2 == 0]
Solve[-1 + x1 + 2 x0 x1 == 0, x1]
Solve[x1^2 + x2 + 2 x0 x2 == 0, x2]
Solve[2 x1 x2 + x3 + 2 x0 x3 == 0, x3]
```

is there a way to solve successive lines of input using previously found?

Comment: Before such functionality was built-in with the `Asymptotic*` family of solvers, I wrote such a routine for differential equations [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96696/4999)

Comment: It seems you are to use `ReplaceAll (/.)` i.e. `Solve[2 x1 x2 + x3 + 2 x0 x3 == 0, x3] /. Solve[x1^2 + x2 + 2 x0 x2 == 0, x2] /. Solve[-1 + x1 + 2 x0 x1 == 0, x1] /. Solve[x0 + x0^2 == 0, x0]`

Comment: @Artes thank you! still need intermediate values, but this makes life a bit easier, any possibility to make it work for `DSolve[{y1''[x] + y0^2[x] == 0, y1[0] == 0, y1'[0] == 0}, y1[x], 
  x] /. DSolve[{y0''[x] == 0, y0[0] == 1, y0'[0] == 0}, y0[x], x]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are simultaneous equations, so they can be solved at the same time, can't they?

```
x^2 + x - ϵ /. x -> x0 + ϵ x1 + ϵ^2 x2 + ϵ^3 x3
CoefficientList[%, ϵ]
Solve[Thread[% == 0][[;; 4]]]
```

> x0 - ϵ + x1 ϵ + x2 ϵ^2 + x3 ϵ^3 + (x0 + x1 ϵ + x2 ϵ^2 + x3 ϵ^3)^2

> {x0 + x0^2, -1 + x1 + 2 x0 x1, x1^2 + x2 + 2 x0 x2, 2 x1 x2 + x3 + 2 x0 x3, x2^2 + 2 x1 x3, 2 x2 x3, x3^2}

> {{x0 -> -1, x1 -> -1, x2 -> 1, x3 -> -2}, {x0 -> 0, x1 -> 1, x2 -> -1, x3 -> 2}}

The last line above just agrees with the result obtained by [`AsymptoticSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve.html) mentioned by @MichaelE2 in the comment:

```
AsymptoticSolve[x^2 + x - ϵ == 0, {x}, {ϵ, 0, 3}]
```

> {{x -> -1 - ϵ + ϵ^2 - 2 ϵ^3}, {x -> ϵ - ϵ^2 + 2 ϵ^3}}

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do something similar for ODE?

Comment: @2Napasa Sorry, I cannot figure out the question about ODE.